# POSIX pthread_create scrambles the values of variables in a struct, how to avoid that?

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, pthreads, posix

So I have my program here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int const size = 3;


struct Arguments{
    int array[];
    float result1[];
    float result2[];
};


//void calc(int arr[], float rarr1[], float rarr2[], int size);
void* calc(void *param);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){



    time_t t;
    srand((unsigned) time(&t));

    int arr[size][size] = {};
    float rarr1[size][size-1] = {};
    float rarr2[size][size-1] = {};

    for(int x = 0; x < size; x++){
        for(int y = 0; y < size; y++){
            int number = rand()%10;
            arr[x][y] = number;
        }
    }

    for(int x = 0; x < size; x++){
        for(int y = 0; y < size; y++){
            cout << arr[x][y] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;

/////////////////////////////////////////

    pthread_t child;

    struct Arguments input;

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){

        input.array[i] = arr[0][i];
    }

    pthread_create(&child, NULL, calc, (void*)&input);
    pthread_join(child, NULL);

    //calc(&input);

    for(int i = 0; i < size-1; i++){
        rarr1[0][i] = input.result1[i];
        cout << "Test: " << rarr1[0][i] << endl;   
    }

//////////////////////////////////


    return 0;
}

//void calc(int arr[], float rarr1[], float rarr2[], int size){

void* calc(void *param){

    struct Arguments *input = (struct Arguments*)param;

    int arr1[] = {};

    float rarr1[] = {};
    float rarr2[] = {};

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){

        arr1[i] = input->array[i];
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            int a = arr1[i];
            int b = arr1[i+1];

            int difference = a-b;

            if(difference < 0){
                difference = difference * -1;
            }

            float euc = 1 + pow(difference, 2);
            euc = sqrt(euc);

            rarr1[i] = euc;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i <size-1; i++){
        input->result1[i] = rarr1[i];
    }

    for(int i = 0; i <size-1; i++){

        int a = arr1[i];
        int b = arr1[i+1];

        int difference = a-b;

        if(difference < 0){
            difference = difference * -1;
        }

        float apar = (difference/rarr1[i]);

        float result = asin(apar);
        result = result*(180/3.14);

        rarr2[i] = result;
    }

    return NULL;

}
```

The important part that causes the trouble is between `//////` lines but I left the rest of the code for the context, since it might be useful.

So I have the function `calc(param);` that does the important calculation in the program.

It is working just fine as long as I call it myself (by actually including the function call in the code) and the test loop right after it gives the correct results.

However, when I try to use `pthread_create();` to create a new thread that will take care of executing that function, the test loop spits out nonsense and some random huge numbers different each time.

It's kinda weird because the code compiles either way, and literally the only thing that I change is these 2 lines.

What am I doing wrong and why the function spits out garbage when started by the Pthread? Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Where do you specify the allocated sizes of the arrays in `input`??

Comment: Oh I see it now. So I have to actually declare the size of the array when using pthread? I've changed `int array[];` to `int array[size];` and it seems like I am getting the correct result. 

Is this the correct of doing it? I've noticed that the program throws a segmentation fault if I increase the array size.


Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: "So I have to actually declare the size of the array when using pthread?" You always have to specify it. Things like `int array[];` are only valid as function parameters.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @latedeveloper. I've changed all the array declarations to make sure that they include their intended size and my program is working fine. Thank you guys so much for help!

Comment: You should declare the size of any array before you even use it. It boggles my mind that your code doesn't crash even without the other thread.

Comment: I am not sure if this the issue but it looks like you are overwritting some part of the Memory. You have specified an array without a predefined length on the Arguments struct that you haven't allocated memory for and then on a later point you start writting values to that array.(I've just saw the above comments, my page just refreshed after i posted mine <.<)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so if anyone's having a similar problem:

Declare the size of arrays no matter what. It turns out that my program didn't work properly because I initialized my result arrays as `float result1[];` instead of `float result1[size];`